# In Sublime Text 2, how do I open new files in a new tab?

Tags: macos, sublimetext

When I'm editing with files on the server, and I click to edit them, if I'm editing multiple files (say an HTML file and a CSS file) but they open in new windows, which, on my small laptop display is a little inconvenient.

How do I make it open in a new tab, rather than a new window?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

OSX-Only: Add the following to `Preferences > Settings - User` or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> :

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false
```

Comment: People don't forget the comma at the end.
And put it inside curly braces if you have nothing inside your config file yet.

Comment: Tnx, this helped me a lot too

Comment: I really don't see why this is `true` by default at all. It makes my works with Sublime Text really painful...

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same result on Windows?

Comment: Fabricio PH and BoundinCode were almost there. 
Actually, what worked for me on Sublime Text 2 on Mac is:
1. Delete the [] (square brackets it comes with and save the following in the file:

{"open_files_in_new_window": false
}

Comment: So user-friendly design!

Answer (score 23):

This is the correct syntax i.e. use a comma...

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "open_files_in_new_window": false
}
```

Comment: What is the color scheme intended for here?

Comment: it's intended to show an in context example of a setting, though this isn't as clear as it could be

Answer (score 18):

Open up your user preferences file

*Preferences > Settings - User*

Add the following line

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false
```

Make sure you place it withint the `{}`as you may already have some settings in there. Make sure you add the `,`after the previous setting.

Example:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai Bright.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 14.0,
    "open_files_in_new_window": false
}
```

Comment: perfect answer + explanation +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users:
By default the above setting value will be true i.e.
`"open_files_in_new_window": true`

If you are using sidebar then just double click on the file to open it in a new tab.

If the current file is not modified, then by single clicking on a new file, will close the current file and open the new file on the same tab.

Answer (score 1):

I use the sidebar menu. I put the folder holding my file in the sidebar by drag and drop. Search tour file in the menu, then just double click it. 
This will cause it to display in a tab.