# Open Sublime Text from Terminal in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Terminal when I use `.subl`

It returns `-bash: .subl: command not found`

Anyone know how to open Sublime Text 3 from the command line in macOS?

Comment: How have you gone with this? I'm having problems with `subl` for ST3 too. I have created the symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/subl` which points to `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`. I've even added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and `export EDITOR="subl -w"` in my `~/.bash_profile` - yet it still doesn't work and I get the same error.

Comment: I'm having a strange problem wherein I have to actually open the subl folder to get the command to execute.  The following executes:`Angelfirenze$ /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ; exit;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]`  And Sublime Text 3 finally opens in a new session.  I have Homebrew installed and followed the instructions for that.

Comment: If you want to open the file `file.txt` with Sublime Text from the command line, the command `open -a "Sublime Text" file.txt` may be better suited.

Comment: The command isn't `.subl`, it's `subl`.

Comment: After modifying `.bash_profile` make sure to close Terminal and re-open it. This is the only thing that really help me here. I wanna make sure that nobody was stuck on this obvious step but really important ^^

Answer (score 783):

I finally got this to work on my OSX box. I used these steps to get it to work:

1. Test `subl` from your ST installation:

   First, navigate to a small folder in Terminal that you want ST to open and enter the following command:

   ```
    /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl .
   ```

   *NOTE:* You may need to replace `Sublime\ Text.app` in the command above to `Sublime\ Text\ 3.app` or `Sublime\ Text\ 2.app` depending upon where the application is stored in your `Applications` directory. The `.` at the end of the above command opens the current working directory you are located in (again make sure you're in a directory that only contains a few files!).

   If you DO NOT get Sublime Text opening your current working directory then the next set of steps will NOT work. If nothing happens or you get an error from Terminal it will be because it couldn't find the Sublime Text application. This would mean that you would have to check what you've typed (spelling, etc.) OR that Sublime Text isn't installed!
2. Check ".bash_profile":

   Now it's time to create your symbolic link in your `PATH` folder, BUT, before we do, let's check your profile file by using `nano ~/.bash_profile`. These are the following lines that pertain to having `subl` work on the command line for Sublime Text:

   ```
    export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    export EDITOR='subl -w'
   ```

   The first line sets the location where you want Terminal to look for binaries on your machine, I'm going to store my symbolic link in the `/usr/local/bin` directory - I guess you could store it anywhere provided you've notified Terminal where to look for binaries.

   The second line is OPTIONAL and just sets Sublime Text as the default editor. The flag `-w` has been added and you can find out more about flags by going to the Sublime Text docs: [ST4 subl](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html), [ST3 subl](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html#ver-3.2) or [ST2 subl](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

   If you do make any edits to this file once you have closed it, you need to run the command:

   ```
    source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   to compile your newly applied edits. If you see any errors after sourcing your file get them fixed before moving to the final step.
3. Create a symbolic link to Sublime Text:

   Now in your chosen path (I used `/usr/local/bin`) you now enter the following command:

   ```
    ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
   ```

   The `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` being EXACTLY the same location as what you entered and verified as working in STEP 1 above. The `/usr/local/bin/subl` being the location of where you want the symbolic link to be located - needs to be one of your `PATH` locations from STEP 2 above.

   Now when you navigate to a folder or file that you want to open in Sublime Text you now just enter `subl` followed by the name of the file or `.` to open the current working directory.

Comment: I had a problem with ST3 where when I first typed in `subl .` I would get a Sublime editor called `untitled` and it didn't reference any files in the directory I was in. Doing `export EDITOR='subl -w'` to my `.bash_profile` fixed this.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to remove the symlink to the old subl file first.

Comment: this worked beautifully until the last step. I'm getting `ln: /usr/subl: Permission denied` Thoughts?

Comment: I think I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196449/installing-sublime-texts-command-line-tool-subl-in-terminal-permission-denie

Comment: Thx Michael Keenan, worked great with Sublime Text 3 on Mavericks!

Comment: Worked on Sublime 3 running on Lion (10.7.3) :)

Comment: As @mr.musicman found, you may need to use `sudo` in front of the command in step 3.

Comment: If you get `/usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory` run `mkdir /usr/local/bin`. Your machine is telling you that the `/usr/local/bin` folder does not exist, so you can't write to it.

Comment: Worked on Sublime 2 (with variations as per your note, and using sudo before the command as Sarah points out) on Snow Leopard. Thanks!

Comment: One thing that I ran into was I needed to create a bash profile (with: touch ~/.bash_profile). I also did not have a usr/local/bin so I choose usr/local/sbin as the directory (which is the same as bin but requires sudo privileges). If you have permission errors, you should run the command 'sudo' first.

Comment: The big step for me here was the PATH setup. I think my path was off, and that was keeping my symlink from working.

Comment: Worked for me on two separate macs. I appreciate the well written explanation.

Comment: Maybe not everyone knows this - but if you set up the subl link for sublime text 2 (as I did) you either need to remove the existing symbolic link (if you're a mac user like me you know enough to be dangerous but not it all)(

Comment: the only thing that worked after following the instructions, super thorough! Better than the blogpost or the git post I had to waste time on before landing here

Comment: Here is a useful video it will solve your problem to adding sublime with cmd or git bash [Open sublime with git or CMD](https://youtu.be/Co9-jPuNvR8)

Comment: TLDR: `subl` is in `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`.

Comment: I can see "sub" here: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin

I also can see both "sublime" and "subl" here: /usr/local/bin/

However, it cannot work at all!
What could go wrong here?

Comment: Now working!
I removed the symbolic path once using rm -f /usr/local/bin/subl and created it again by your comment. Now it is working!

Comment: Just curious - what's the benefit of doing all the sym linking rather than just throwing a function in your .zshrc or .bashrc? For example, `╰─➤  show-function subl

subl () {
 /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl $1
}`

Answer (score 502):

For Mac OS 10.8+ (tested up to Sonoma 14.1.1):

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

worked.

Comment: I had to use the home directory, ~, instead of /usr/bin, to make this work for me ... "sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl"

Comment: This is working but it's not opening the same folded where I ran Subl

Comment: For sublime2
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl`

Comment: Worked on OS X 10.10.4

Comment: @Tinple I am sorry I haven't tried it on 10.11, I guess the same thing should work

Comment: @Tinple This works in 10.11 `sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
`  See the answer here for why - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196224/unix-ln-s-command-not-permitted-in-osx-el-capitan-beta3

Comment: I'm new to Mac and I tried for quite sometime to make it work. Let me tell the reason why other straight forward answers didnt work. While installing Sublime Text for the first time , remember it will ask "Just for you or everyone" , so it is installed in the Applications folder found in your ROOT. Even though it will show under your Applications. Hence this SUDO (Super user Do , played a vital role). First thing Im learning UNIX/LINUX whatever. Wanted to share this learning.

Comment: Worked on OSX 10.11.4

Comment: it is not fixing for me. I have this set up.       ~ > source ~/.bash_profile 
~ > echo $EDITOR                                                                                               
subl -w                    
~ > subl .                 
~ > which subl             
/Users/vishlpa4/bin/subl   
~ > ls -al ~/bin/subl      
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  62 Oct  8 18:22 /Users/vishlpa4/bin/subl -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl...but still sublime pops up with untitled file when I do "sublime filename".

Comment: In 2018 Only Ross's comment works, @Ross Please add your comment as answer it will definitely help others.

Comment: 2021 update : I'm using Big Sur 11.1, worked perfectly

Comment: Didn’t work for me and failed with below lines:
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory

Please suggest

Comment: Worked on 11.6.

Comment: 2022 update: works fantastic on macOS Monterey 12.2.1 - thank you!

Comment: export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code:/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"

Comment: Worked on Monterey 12.3 thank you

Comment: Still working perfectly on MacOS 12.6 (21G115).

Comment: This worked on macOS Ventura 13.14.1

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ \(4143\).app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

Comment: This worked on 14.1 as well

Answer (score 218):

Assuming:

- You have already installed Homebrew.
- /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.
- You are on Yosemite or El Capitain.

MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 works as well confirmed by David Rawson and MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 confirmed by Alexander K.

Run the following script in Terminal to create the specific symlink.

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Then:

```
subl .
```

Hit <kbd>Return</kbd> and it should instantly open Sublime Text.

Comment: @ChutipongRoobklom Thanks. It worked for me on `macOS Sierra Version: 10.12 (16A323)`.

Comment: Working on macOS Sierra 10.12.5. Thanks

Comment: Can confirm that works on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 as well. Thank you!

Comment: my sublime text path was different I guess it because I am using sublime 2 ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl

Comment: Works on High Sierra OSX 10.13.3

Comment: it gives me this:
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
What do I need to do?

Comment: This works for me but it opens sublime as a "device", and my mac seems to think its different than opening sublime via the icon because i can get 2 sublimes on my dock. Why do I see sublime appear as an ejectable device when i open it with the command line after adding this to bash_profile??

Comment: @Reihan_amn - late reply and I think you solved it already, but just as a reference. There seems to be an existing link associated to that name. You can use rm /usr/local/bin/subl then you can perform executing the symbolic link

Comment: Works on Catalina 10.15

Comment: Awesome!I can confirm that it still works on Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Works on Big Sur 11.4. Thanks

Comment: works on Monterey beta

Answer (score 93):

I'm using oh-my-zsh on Mac OSX Mavericks and the symbol link didn't work for me, so I added an alias in my .zshrc file instead:

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

Open a new terminal and you should be good to go, and type `subl`.

Comment: Same here, but for Bash.

Comment: Same here, this worked for me, but I needed to change it to Sublime text 2 with this string: "Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/"

Comment: This is for ST 2 i guess. ST 3 comes with CLI but i can't run it yet.

Comment: @emrah I am using ST3

Comment: @ThomasBindzus I figured out later. Thanks.

Comment: All you had to do is uncoment the export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 in .zshrc and then source ~/.zshrc

Comment: Everyone should be using oh-my-zsh anyways, so upvoted for visibility!

Answer (score 70):

This worked for me (I'm using OS X Mavericks)

First, create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```

Now you can open sublime with

```
subl "/a/path/to/the/directory/you/want/to/open"
```

Comment: I had to sudo rm /usr/bin/subl to make it work on OSX 10.9, thanks!

Comment: ln -s  /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl  /usr/local/bin/subl

Comment: why do we need quotes? it works with quotes for me, but does not work without them?

Comment: ln: /usr/bin/subl: Operation not permitted

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. Use `/usr/local/bin/subl`, instead of `/usr/bin/subl`.

Answer (score 67):

The one I will use is very simple.

```
open -a "sublime text" [file]
```

this opens up the sublime text right away. You can  specify the file to open as an optional parameter, e.g. to open "myfile.txt" in the current directory.

Comment: If you faster access you can create an alias. Type nano .bash_profile and paste in: alias subl="open -a 'sublime text'"

Comment: Thank you! It's the only solution that worked for me. To make it open in a new tab in the existing window (not in a new one), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961350/in-sublime-text-2-how-do-i-open-new-files-in-a-new-tab

Comment: I think this is the cleanest option of all. Thanks!

Comment: How do you modify this so that it will create a file that doesn't actually exist? I know how to use open -a sublimetext to open a file that exists, but if i'm creating a new textfile, what should i modify the open script to?

Comment: I don't understand why we have to create symbolic links n all when this solution is SO MUCH better

Comment: works flawlessly

Answer (score 61):

You can create a new alias in Terminal:

```sh
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Copy this line and paste it into the editor:

```sh
alias subl='open -a "Sublime Text"'
```

Hit <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd> to save and close it.

Close all Terminal windows and open it up again.

That's it, you can now use `subl filename` or `subl .`

**Update for zsh**:

Default shell was changed to zsh since macOS 10.15 Catalina.

```sh
nano ~/.zshrc
```

The rest of the steps remain the same.

Comment: Didn’t work for me with
zsh: command not found: subl

Comment: This is the most straightforward way to do this.

Comment: @JyotiDuhan zsh was added above.

Comment: I think there are ways around this, but as given,  this solution will fail when an argument feed to the _subl_ alias is a non-existent file.  I fount it more reliable to just extend PATH to include the sublime /path dir as suggested by @Artemiy

Comment: Or: `alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl $*"`

Comment: after adding  alias into ~/.bash_profile, do `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: After adding the alias in your ~/.bash_profile you can hit esc --> :wq! to force save the changes in MacOS as well if you are in vi mode. Then do source ~/.bash_profile to refresh the environment variables to sync the changes made without having to close and reopen your terminal session.

Answer (score 28):

There is a easy way to do this. It only takes a couple steps and you don't need to use the command line too much. If you new to the command line this is the way to do it.

***Step 1 : Finding the bin file to put the subl executable file in***

1. Open up the terminal
2. type in `cd ..` ---------------------this should go back a directory
3. type in `ls` ------------------------to see a list of files in the directory
4. type in `cd ..` ---------------------until you get a folder that contains **usr**
5. type in `open usr` ---------------this should open the finder and you should see some folders
6. open up the **bin** folder -------this is where you will copy your sublime executable file.

***Step 2: Finding the executable file***

1. open up the **finder**
2. Under file open up a new finder window (CMD + N)
3. Navigate to **applications** folder
4. find Sublime Text and right click so you get a pulldown menu
5. Click on Show Package Content
6. Open up Content/SharedSupport/bin
7. Copy the **subl** file
8. Paste it in the bin folder in the **usr** folder we found earlier
9. In the terminal type in `subl` --------------this should open Sublime Text

Make sure that it gets copied and it's not a shortcut. If you do have a problem, view the usr/bin folder as icons and paste the **subl** in a empty area in the folder. It should not have a shortcut arrow in the icon image.

Comment: After trying the other answers, this one was the only one to work for me. Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.

Comment: This did not work for me on Mac OS X El Capitan -- I was unable to copy to file over. Chutipong Roobklom's answer did work, however.

Comment: As of El Capitan's and up, you need to paste the subl file in the /usr/local/bin folder. So follow step 2 to point 6, open it in the terminal and execute the command sudo cp subl /usr/local/bin. This is because of the new System Integrity Protection feature.

Answer (score 21):

Try this.

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: ^ Use this one. Soft-links into /usr/*local*/bin.

Answer (score 17):

The Symlink command from the [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) documentation won't work as there is no `~/bin/` directory in Home location on Mac OS X El Capitan or later.

So, we'll need to place the symlink on the `/usr/local/bin` as this path would be in our `$PATH` variable *in most cases*.

So, the following command should do the trick:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Once you create the symlink correctly, you would be able to run the Sublime Text 3 like this: `subl .` *(. means the current directory)*

Answer (score 16):

Just follow the **[Sublime Documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html#mac)**

### Bash

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

### ZSH

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

### Linux

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl
```

---

*Make sure you close the terminal after run the command.*

### Usage

To see the available flags, run `subl --help`.

Answer (score 12):

Please note not to write into `/usr/bin` but instead into `/usr/local/bin`.
The first one is for app that write themselves the binary into the system and the latest is for that specific usage of making our own system-wide binaries (which is our case here when symlinking).

Also `/usr/local/bin` is read after `/usr/bin` and therefore also a good place to override any default app.

Considering this, the right symlinking would be:

`ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

Answer (score 12):

Close Sublime. Run this command. It will uninstall it. You won't lose your prefs. Then run it again. It will automatically bind `subl`.

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/sublime-text
```

Comment: This finally did it, thank you so much for posting this! I've been trying to get ST3 to run from the command line for months after the original symlink broke for some reason.  Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but just running it twice was not enough, had to remove the existing sublime with `sudo rm -rf` on the sublime directory in the applications folder first.

Answer (score 11):

**The following worked for me**

```
open -a Sublime\ Text file_name.txt
open -a Sublime\ Text Folder_Path
```

**You can use alias to make it event simple like**

Add the following line in your

> ~/.bash_profile

```
alias sublime="open -a Sublime\ Text $@"
```

**Then next time you can use following command to open files/folders**

```
sublime file_name.txt
sublime Folder_Path
```

Comment: And any way for opening several files in the same window? Because each time it opens a new one... (I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023529/how-to-open-files-and-folders-in-same-window-in-sublime-text-on-macos) but without success). Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In OS X Mavericks running Sublime Text 2 the following worked for me.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```

Its handy to locate the file in the finder and drag and drop that into the terminal window so you can be sure the path is the correct one, I'm not a huge terminal user so this was more comfortable for me. then you can go to the start of the path and start adding in the other parts like the shorthand UNIX commands. Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

It works !!!! for me on MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

and find it in terminal `subl`

Answer (score 9):

Adding this to ur .bashrc or .zshrc is a simple solution.

```
alias sublime="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"
```

Answer (score 9):

Starting with macOS Catalina (ver 10.15) zsh is used. To allow Sublime to run from the command line, edit `.zshrc` in your home directory (`cd` with no arguments will get you there) and add the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin"
```

To run Sublime Text from the command line use `subl [filename]`

Answer (score 7):

if you have subl set up to be called from the command line, the proper command to open the current directory is:

`subl .`

"[OS X Command Line](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)" is a link on how to make sure everything is set up.

Comment: It returns `ln: /Users/###/bin/subl: No such file or directory`

Comment: did you look at the link at the bottom of my answer?  try to following command `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl`

Comment: @danmanstx I've created the symbolic link in my `/usr/local/bin` directory yet it still gives me the error. I note that my ST3 package has been installed at `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/...` and have made the distinction when creating my symbolic link. Yet the error remains - I think it has something to do with my `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: In my case the link points to ```ln -s /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't pollute /usr/bin directory unless you really need to.
I always use /usr/local/bin for those binaries that aren't managed by the distribution package manager. Why? Because if the package manager gets updated it'll always replace the files in /usr/bin.

So what I'd do is

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

Answer (score 7):

You can just add an alias

```
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

Then you should be able to open a folder or whatever with

```
subl <path>
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [Sublime setup documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html#mac)

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

Works fine.

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 7):

This answer is for **Mac OS Ventura** and **Sublime Text 4** (build 4143) specifically, which breaks the usual method of symlinking `<APP_PATH>/bin/subl` to `/usr/local/bin`.

A clean and simple solution to this is to use `alias`-ing. From any relevant files like: `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` add:

`alias subl="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_text"`

Then, `source ~/.zshrc`.

The command `subl` should work.

Answer (score 4):

This is to get it working as an ALIAS, not a Symbolic link!

This will allow you to run additional commands in the terminal without interrupting the subl session.   Using many of the symbolic link answers here (`ln -s`), cause the terminal process to endure while using Sublime text.  If you want the separation, create an alias in the Bash profile like so:

1. Test `subl` from your ST installation:

   First, navigate to a folder in Terminal that you want ST to open and enter the following command:

   ```
   /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl .
   ```

   *NOTE:* You may need to replace `Sublime\ Text.app` in the command above to `Sublime\ Text\ 3.app` or `Sublime\ Text\ 2.app` depending upon where the application is stored in your `Applications` directory. The `.` at the end of the above command opens the current working directory you are located in (again make sure you're in a directory that only contains a few files!).

   If you DO NOT get Sublime Text opening your current working directory then the next set of steps will NOT work. If nothing happens or you get an error from Terminal it will be because it couldn't find the Sublime Text application. This would mean that you would have to check what you've typed (spelling, etc.) OR that Sublime Text isn't installed!
2. Check and update ".bash_profile":

   Now add the alias in your Bash Profile. Open it via `vim ~/.bash_profile`. These are the following lines that pertain to having `subl` work on the command line for Sublime Text:

   ```
   ## For Sublime Text 3 alias
   alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
   ## For Sublime Text global editor preference **Optional
   export EDITOR='subl -w'
   ```

   I suggest always commenting your code in here with `##`.  The second line is OPTIONAL and just sets Sublime Text as the default editor. The flag `-w` has been added and you can find out more about flags by going to the Sublime Text docs: [ST3 subl](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) or [ST2 subl](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

   If you do make any edits to this file once you have closed it, you need to `source` this file in your current session or close the terminal (tab) and open a new one. You can `source` this file by running the command `source ~/.bash_profile` Resolve any errors before moving to the final step.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for opening a file with Sublime on mac from terminal

```
open 'path/file.txt' -a '/Applications/Sublime Text.app'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add that if you are upgrading from Sublime Text 2, go into /usr/bin and delete your old subl first before following the same instructions above. It's worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I achieve this with just one line in terminal (with Sublime 3):

```
alias subl='/usr/local/bin/sublime'
```

Answer (score 2):

**I am using mac airbook open your terminal and type**

```
 sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```

**Then type simple subl and file name**

```
 subl index.py
```

Comment: See below, use the one with /usr/*local*/bin. Try not to add custom softlinks into system directories.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the different ways you can accomplish it:

1. To open sublime text from terminal

```
open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/
```

2. To open a specific file in current path (or provide path to the file you need to open) using sublime text

```
open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/ myFileToOpen.txt
```

3. Make your command short by introducing a new alias named 'sublime' and use it

   a. open bash_profile:

   `nano ~/.bash_profile`

   b. copy this line to create the alias and save and restart terminal

   `alias sublime="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"`

   c. usage: apple.txt will open with sublime text (provide file path if necessary)

   `sublime apple.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Oh-My-Zshell and the previous aliases stated didn't work for me so I wrote a simple bash function that will allow you to open Sublime from the command line by using `sublime` to open the current folder in the editor. With the addition functionality to specify a file to open the editor from.

```
# Open Sublime from current folder or specified folder
sublime(){
  /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ./$1
}
```

Usage to open current folder in terminal:

```
$ sublime
```

Usage to open specific folder:

```
$ sublime path/to/the/file/to/open
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the file in the *Default* path **did not work for me** as the `Menu.sublime-menu` file has overridden almost all other menu options and left me with **only** the custom one.

What worked for me is creating the below file in path `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Main.sublime-menu` (note directory *User* instead of *Default*):

```
[
    {
        "caption": "File",
        "mnemonic": "F",
        "id": "file",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "caption": "Open Recent More",
                "children":
                [
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 1 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 2 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 3 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 4 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 5 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 6 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 7 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 8 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 9 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 10 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 11 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 12 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 13 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 14 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 15 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 16 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 17 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 18 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 19 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 20 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 21 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 22 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 23 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 24 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 25 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 26 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 27 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 28 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 29 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 30 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 31 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 32 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 33 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 34 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 35 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 36 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 37 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 38 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 39 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 40 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 41 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 42 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 43 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 44 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 45 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 46 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 47 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 48 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 49 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 50 } }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

### Result:

(needed to blur some parts of the image for security reasons)

[image: open-recent-more.png]

Answer (score 0):

For Sublime 4+ it's even simpler with Bash:

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm on a mac and this worked for me:

```
open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```