# Open git diff in sublime from command line

Tags: git, pipe, diff, sublimetext

How can I open a git diff in sublime from the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have the subl command accessible from the command line:
[Open Sublime Text from Terminal in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/opening-sublime-text-on-command-line-as-subl-on-mac-os?lq=1)

Next, in your .profile or .bashrc or wherever you keep your aliases, add:

```
#open diff in sublime. 
#ex: gd   
#ex: gd head^   
#ex: gd 7b3f441147f7c3c4b27bb7c9658aef27e3d0a5eb ee49bbc57f7376bc9f5c951e13808cb6b66be3d8
gd() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
            git diff | subl
        else
            git diff $@ | subl
    fi
}
```

And you can now open your diffs in sublime right from your terminal.

Comment: This has worked great for years and appears to have regressed in Build 4107. Searching for any updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this as a one-off, and if you are comparing `a` and `b` with `subl` as an alias for Sublime, you can write `git diff a b | subl` as per the body of the above