# How to edit React Native tools?

Tags: react-native

**PRO TIP**

When you see **Red Box** with stack trace, you can click any 
  stack frame to jump to the source file. The packager will launch your 
  editor of choice. It will first look at **REACT_EDITOR** environment 
  variable, then at **EDITOR**. To set it up, you can add something like 
  `REACT_EDITOR=atom` to your `.bashrc`.

**.bashrc:**

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go

export REACT_EDITOR=atom
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: That's not a question. If you want to provide information like this, you must follow the Stack Overflow Q&A format: good, clear, well researched question in the question box, detailed answer in the answer box.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not follow the Q&A format.

Comment: "PRO TIP" is what the output of the react-native-cli show when you click on an error message.

Answer (score 17):

## For Visual Studio Code

Add code below to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
export REACT_EDITOR=code
```

Comment: So, this is for a Mac, isn't it? And what about Ubuntu, on a vscode installed through Ubuntu Software (snap)?

Answer (score 3):

When you see Red Box with stack trace, you can click any stack frame to jump to the source file. The packager will launch your editor of choice. It will first look at REACT_EDITOR environment variable, then at EDITOR.

To set it up, you can add something like REACT_EDITOR=atom to your .bashrc.

```
# .bashrc
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export REACT_EDITOR=atom
```

Comment: how  to change   Sublime  Text 2 ?export REACT_EDITOR=Sublime  Text 2 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/opening-sublime-text-on-command-line-as-subl-on-mac-os

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Visual studio code ?

Answer (score 1):

To set it up, you can add something like  REACT_EDITOR=atom to your .bashrc or .profile.

```
    #.profile
    export NVM_DIR="/usr/local/nvm"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
    export REACT_EDITOR="atom" # Add atom to REACT_EDITOR for scripting
```

If you do make any edits to this file once you have closed it, you need to run the command in your command line:

```
    source ~/.profile
```

to compile your newly applied edits. If you see any errors after sourcing your file get them fixed before moving to the final step.
For my example,it works in .profile,but doesn't work in .bashrc. I guess it is related with NVM_DIR path.I hope it can help you:)