# Sublime Text 3 on command Line

Tags: shell, command-line, sublimetext3, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed zsh and ohmyzsh. I followed an instruction to open sublime text 3 on the commandline by typing sublime in the folder.
Instead of typing the whole 'sublime' word, can I just open it by typing 'subl' to open sublime? If so how on ohmyzsh?

When I execute echo $PATH, it returns /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Thank you in advance for helping out.

********************Edited********************
For those who are having issues try the EASY way.
Fidner go to the root dir
Application
find sublime right click 'show content'
contents/sharedSupport/bin  ==> there should be a file 'subl'

now go back to root dir and usr/local/bin and look for subl or sublime. delete those and paste the recently copied subl.

Should work like a charm.

Comment: tried
 ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
it doesn't work either.

Comment: In /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin, there is a file subl. Why is that it is opening when i type 'sublime' ? and not 'subl .'

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a way to set an alias in zsh: https://askubuntu.com/questions/31216/setting-up-aliases-in-zsh

Answer (score 1):

Create a symlink from Sublime binary to /usr/local/bin. Symlink can be any name

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  I followed the path to where sublime was located in my /Applications directory and created a symbolic link to my local executable programs.  It should work for you too. If /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/ does not lead to subl than it will not work.  You might need to sudo to cd and to ln -s.

`ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

I found this information from this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/opening-sublime-text-on-command-line-as-subl-on-mac-os). Also, this Unix answer helped me understand the [/usr/local/bin/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259231/difference-between-usr-bin-and-usr-local-bin) path better. This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux) is great too. I hope it helps.

Comment: It probably needs sudo:

sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin