# How to launch Sublime and define the file syntax in one go?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Sound as lazy as it is I was wondering if it's possible to open a file with sublime using (command line) and in the same command define the expected syntax.

Lets say on a mac we have the [subl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/opening-sublime-text-on-command-line-as-subl-on-mac-os) command installed, so running `$ subl .bash_something` will open the **.bash_something** then we have to chose the "shel script(bash)" syntax from the list. what would be really nice (for laze me) is to include the syntax to the command as an argument. i.e.

```
$ subl -x bash .bash_something
```

or something like that. this obviously doesn't work but I was wondering if there is similar solution or if its possible to include one

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way that I can find to dynamically set the syntax from the command line. `subl` has the `--command` option, which allows you to run a Sublime command while loading the file, directory, or project indicated. However, the command to change the syntax of a view - `set_file_type` - takes an argument of the form `("syntax": "Packages/PackageName/SyntaxName.sublime-syntax")` (or `SyntaxName.tmLanguage`). As far as I've been able to tell, you simply can't pass arguments to commands run via the command line. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1109) to request an enhancement.

Now, this doesn't mean that all is lost. If you have just a few filetypes that are unknown to Sublime, open them, then select **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as...`** and select the syntax you want. If for some reason this isn't sufficient, or would like finer-grained control over exactly which filenames (not just which extensions) get opened as what, check out the [`ApplySyntax`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax) plugin. It allows you to use regexes to open exactly which file patterns you define as what syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Commands can take arguments in Sublime 3 now. I was able to achieve this functionality with a bash function.

You can pass arguments to the `--command` option with inline JSON and escaped quotes. This command will change the syntax to Bash for the current active file in Sublime:

```
subl --command "set_setting {\"setting\": \"syntax\", \"value\": \"Packages/ShellScript/Shell-Unix-Generic.sublime-syntax\"}"
```

I created a simple bash function and sourced it in my `.bash_profile` to wrap these two commands together to activate/open a file then change the synax:

```
function subl_bash() {
    subl "$1" && subl --command "set_setting {\"setting\": \"syntax\", \"value\": \"Packages/ShellScript/Shell-Unix-Generic.sublime-syntax\"}"
}
```