# How to open files with sublime text 3 from terminal?

Tags: path, ubuntu-14.04, sublimetext3

Is there a way to do it? I looked for a similar question but only found one on MAC OSX. However, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: just use `subl path_to_file` - `subl` should be on your path

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/273034/lauching-sublime-text-from-command-line

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes ,There's a way. Just Use the command `subl` to open sublime text from terminal.
if you want to open a specific file use `subl path/to/the/file`.

But sublime text must be installed using ppa.
  For particular installation of sublime text 3 using ppa refer [This Link on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3/227617#227617) .

Comment: `` for mac this has to be run first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18842982/10018427

Answer (score 4):

Terminal Command

> `$ subl modules/custom/js/drop-down.js`

Comment: A score hunter's addition