# cannot get sublime text 3 command line tools to work

Tags: bash, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I had sublime text 2 command line tools working.  When I downloaded Sublime Text 3, I could not get the command line tools to work.  I've tried every answer here: [Open Sublime Text from Terminal in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/opening-sublime-text-on-command-line-as-subl-on-mac-os).  When I type:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

I get back:

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
```

but no matter what I do I still get back `-bash: subl: command not found`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the existing link first. It must be a broken link.

List the contents of the directory and you'll see that the link is broken:

```
$ ls -Al /usr/local/bin/
```

Output from the above command will show that the existing link is pointing to a non existing file. So delete the broken link:

```
$ rm /usr/local/bin/subl
```

You might need to use sudo for the above command.

Now you can create the symlink:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and nothing seemed to work. Also, if you have Sublime 2, remember to use:

`ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

I was not getting it right at first because I forgot the version!