# Rails 5.2 Can't open rails credentials with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux with Rails 5.2 and Sublime Text 3.
When i do

EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit

It says "New credentials encrypted and saved." but does not open the file to be edited with Sublime Text 3.
Also when trying Visual Studio Code with

EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit

Visual Studio Code opens but it is empty.

I can only edit the file with VIM and the command 
EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit

The thing is i do not want to edit the file with vim.
What is the problem so it does not open the file to be edited with Sublime or VS Code?

I am using Rails 5.2

Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Answer (score 9):

On macOS, you would run this command to edit the credentials in Sublime. When you are done, save and close the file in Sublime:

```
EDITOR="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -w" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Answer (score 5):

I am on windows 7x64 and stumbled upon this issue this morning.Solved it by adding atom to my system variable Path(so cmd & powershell & bash all know about it) and by adding powershell to my environment.I use separate environment for ruby & rails.

So now when I type `set EDITOR=atom --wait && rails credentials:edit` in cmd or

1st `$env:EDITOR="atom --wait"`, 2nd `rails credentials:edit`in powershell or

`EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` in bash,

I get the desired result wich is to open credentials and edit them :).. Hope this helps

PS. I didn't need to use `--wait` flag when setting the editor to subl or notepad!
`EDITOR` is just a temporary variable for the current session, meaning for the cmd,powershell or bash window that is opened at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

By default Sublime Text Editor is not configured to be run directly from the command line. You're trying to set the EDITOR variable to "subl --wait", but the command line doesn't know what "subl" is! Try this post which goes into detail on setting up a "subl" alias for starting up sublime on the command line, then try again!

[Open Sublime Text from Terminal in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/open-sublime-text-from-terminal-in-macos)

EDIT: Noticed you are on Ubuntu and not MacOS, but that post should still work as long as you're using bash, which is the default shell on Ubuntu.

Comment: I did configure subl command in Terminal, so when i type subl it opens Sublime Text 3. Same thing as sublime happens with Atom, Notepad, Wordpad

Comment: Noticed a typo in your VS Code example, you need a space between `code` and `--wait`, not a regular sublime user, but I did get it to work with Atom like this:

    `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit`

Comment: i copied code --wait wrong. I am running it with code --wait.
When i am trying to run it with Atom, i get same  behavior with VS Code (empty file)

Comment: Are you able to open Atom/Code from the terminal, i.e. `atom .` or `code .` to open the current directory?

Comment: yes i am able to open Atom/Code from the terminal to current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded my following this

```
 SET EDITOR="full_path to sublime"
 rails credentials:edit
```

after closing sublime only i am getting new credentials saved response.

Hope it helps