# How to fix opening sublime from terminal in MacOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, sublimetext3

I want to be able to open the sublime text editor in MacOS (14.10.6) from the command line. I found several instructions how to do that ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/open-sublime-text-from-terminal-in-macos) and [HERE](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal)), but of course it does not work for me.

I did create the symbolic link to the application in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sublime -> /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

The file at location `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` ***does*** exist. Also, the folder `/usr/local/bin` is ***included*** in the actual definition of `PATH`.

However, the command is not found when I enter it on the command line in a terminal

```
~$ sublime
-bash: sublime: command not found
```

**Proof:**

```
$ls -al /usr/local/bin | grep sublime
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root    admin        63 Jan 15 07:44 sublime -> /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:/Users/adietz/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/adietz/.pyenv/shims:/Users/adietz/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Show output from `ls -al /usr/local/bin | grep sublime` please. Also output from `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Seee updated question with the "proof"

Comment: It's interesting that it's owned by `root`. That seems wrong but I don't see how it would hurt anything.

Comment: Yes, saw that too, changed that to my user - but still does not change the outcome. I still get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `open` command, as the manual says:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
> The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had
> double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the
> default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the
> specified files.
> ```

Option `-a` is suitable for MacOS applications, then

```
open -a sublime\ text
```

(or alike) should work.

You can then alias it and call it when needed:

```
alias sublime="open -a sublime\ text"
sublime
```

Comment: `open -a sublime` does not work to begin with, neither `open -a subl`.

Comment: But `alias sublime="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`  is working

Comment: @alex Right! This is because the application name is "Sublime Text" not "Sublime", change accordingly...

Comment: @alex don't link to executable directly, prefer using the *name* of the app

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès `Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` is the command-line utility that users are *supposed* to link to. The actual macOS binary is located elsewhere, `subl` is just a script that invokes it properly.

Comment: adding 'subl@ -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' to /usr/local/bin worked. 

adding 'sublime@ -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_text' did NOT.

Ty for this