# Sublime Text - Filezilla - Open files in new tabs - Windows 8

Tags: tabs, sublimetext2, sublimetext, filezilla

Whenever I click "View/Edit" in Filezilla, the file opens in a new window at Sublime Text. How do I set the files to open as new tabs at the same window?

I tried: `"open_files_in_new_window": false`, but it doesn't work. I guess it is for MAC only but not Windows?

I am running Windows 8 64bit, Sublime Text 2.0.2, and FileZilla 3.9.0.6

Comment: Yes, open_files_in_new_window is marked "OSX Only" . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961350/in-sublime-text-2-how-do-i-open-new-files-in-a-new-tab

Comment: Any idea how to fix this for Windows 8?

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=64638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case it's connected with ST 3 but you can give it a try or use version 3.

Answer by `tsunami141` from http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=64638

> I was able to find a solution to this. If anyone else is looking for
>   the answer at all, it was a problem with my filezilla filetype
>   associations. I was unable to get .html files to open in sublime text
>   so i had to edit the filezilla filetype associations settings to: 
>   html "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" - open
>
> I fixed the problem by removing the " - open" from the end of that
>   text, now all files open in tabs in the same window. Hope this helps
>   someone!

Comment: Great find! I was searching frantically for the fix to this and I saw your answer and realized.... I am Tsunami141. :(

Comment: @mcheah, I should transfer these 2 upvotes to you :)

Comment: Worked for me as well on Windows 10. This was driving me nuts; thanks!